# How to write in the manifest file?

Tags: java, maven, manifest, pom.xml

My manifest file is not updated, I used the plugin maven-war-plugin to write, but nothing happened, if I change the name of the directory of the manifest file I get an error `manifest file not found` while packaging , but when I put it in the right place nothing happens, the content of the file is unchanged.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
          <addMavenDescriptor/>
          <compress/>
          <forced/>
          <index/>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath/>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries/>
            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries/>
            <addExtensions/>
            <classpathLayoutType/>
            <classpathMavenRepositoryLayout/>
            <classpathPrefix/>
            <customClasspathLayout/>
            <mainClass/>
            <packageName/>
          </manifest>
          <manifestEntries>
            <key>value</key>
          </manifestEntries>
          <manifestFile>src/main/webapp/META-INF/test/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
          <pomPropertiesFile/>
        </archive>
    </configuration>                
</plugin>
```

and the content of my manifest file is:

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

Any idea, why it doesn't work or how it can be done correctly?

Comment: What do you expect to be written in the Manifest file?

Comment: the corresponding tags even if they are empty like class-path and so

Comment: Have you checked in your parent poms and your local settings.xml to see if you're overriding manifest generation anywhere? I tried your example, and got the same results, but then found that we have a manifest entry in our parent pom's parent that was messing things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use an empty tag. 
You should set the boolean parameter to true:

```
   <manifest>
      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
    </manifest>
```

See the [official doc](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-manifest-guide.html)

Comment: i did it but nothing happened

Comment: I have tried it by myself and it works. Have you take a look at the manifest inside yout war?

Comment: it's late yes i know, but your are right, inside the war file the manifest file was written, anyway I will post the entire solution, may be it will be useful for someone else

Answer (score 0):

the whole solution :

add to your pom.xml file the maven war plugin or another plugin that supports the archive tag inside its configuration :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                </manifest>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
                    <Build-Host>${agent.name}</Build-Host>
                    <Build-User>${user.name}</Build-User>
                    <Build-Maven>Maven ${maven.version}</Build-Maven>
                    <Build-Java>${java.version}</Build-Java>
                    <Build-OS>${os.name}</Build-OS>
                    <Build-Label>${project.version}</Build-Label>
                    <Build-Path>${basedir}</Build-Path>
                </manifestEntries>
                <manifestFile>src/main/webapp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

we can specify the format of the build time also by adding the tag properties for the pom configuration :

```
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>dd/MM/yyyy</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

those properties are written automatically in the Manifest file inside the war after each build :

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Build-Time: 15/09/2014
    Build-Java: 1.7.0_60
    Class-Path: commons-codec-1.9.jar 
     javax.mail-1.5.0.jar activation-1.1.jar joda-time-2.3.jar spring-ldap
     -core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar spring-data-commons-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar jcl-ove
     r-slf4j-1.7.1.jar
    Built-By: aXSEDZ
    Created-By: Apache Maven
    Build-Host: 
    Build-Path: C:\WSLocal\5portal\5portalweb
    Build-OS: Windows 7
    Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_60
    Build-Maven: Maven null
    Build-Label: 0.0.5-SNAPSHOT
    Build-User: aXSEDZ
    Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

After that read the file as a resource file, in my case i access it throw a spring context :

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
        WebApplicationContext webAppContext = ContextLoaderListener.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
        if (webAppContext != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = webAppContext.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
            props.load(inputStream);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```